# offset last li in a centeres li's list

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists, responsive

I have a centered `LI`'s `UL` (like those default navigation bars...) - see code below.

Now i want to make a little weird adjustment to that. i want the last li to stay sticked to the left of the last li before him (just like float: left) but without him taking space in the ul, so the other li's will be in the center and he will just be sticking in the side (maybe just like an absolute position's element will...). another thing is i that i need to work when this weird li is alone in the ul also. here is an image that explains better:
[weird sticky li image before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3siV2.png)

and here is a [codepen playground with that](https://codepen.io/bentalgad/pen/OgXLdK).

Also a built-in one here:

```css
*{font-size:24px;text-align:center;}
.con { background: #aaa; }
.navbar { background: #eee; width:70%;margin:auto;}
.navbar li{display:inline-block; padding: 4px 8px; border: 1px solid blue;}

.last{color:red;}

.afterlast{margin-right:-78.6px;}
```

```html
BEFORE:
<div class="con">
<nav class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
<li>HOME</li>
<li>ABOUT</li>
<li>STUFF</li>
<li>CONTACT</li>
<li class="last">WEIRD</li>
</ul>
</nav><!-- /.navbar -->
</div>
AFTER:
<div class="con">
<nav class="navbar">
<ul class="nav">
<li>HOME</li>
<li>ABOUT</li>
<li>STUFF</li>
<li>CONTACT</li>
<li class="last afterlast">WEIRD</li>
</ul>
</nav><!-- /.navbar -->
</div>
```

Now I prefer a pure css solution if possible and of course it should be responsive.

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/eRzYvV

Comment: it is, but i need it to work when the weird li is alone in the ul also. it's a little bit complicated situation where this li acts as search and the other li's are "added tags like...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, combining the answer and comments made by the grateful users, this is the best answer (pure css):

1. Using absolute positioning.
2. Using the `:first-child:last-child` to set position to relative when the weird li is alone.

Here it is live:

```css
* {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.con {
  background: #aaa;
}

.navbar {
  background: #eee;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.last {
  color: red;
}

.afterlast:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: .25em;
}

.afterlast:first-child:last-child {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>BEFORE:</h2>
<div class="con">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>STUFF</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
      <li class="last">WEIRD</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
</div>
<h2>AFTER:</h2>
<div class="con">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>STUFF</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
      <li class="last afterlast">WEIRD</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
</div>

<h2>AFTER ALONE:</h2>
<div class="con">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li class="last afterlast">WEIRD</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
</div>
```

Thanks to: @sorayadragon, @JaKhris and @Michael Coker.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add an additional class to that li element when it's by itself so you can adjust the styles and make it take up space again. I added the `.aloneweird` class and adjusted its styles. Additionally, I removed the `padding-left` from the `ul` element which was making it uncentered.

```css
* {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.con {
  background: #aaa;
}

.navbar {
  background: #eee;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.last {
  color: red;
}

.afterlast {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: .25em;
}

.aloneweird {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>AFTER:</h2>
<div class="con">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>HOME</li>
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      <li>STUFF</li>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
      <li class="last afterlast">WEIRD</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
</div>

<h2>ALONE:</h2>
<div class="con">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="last afterlast aloneweird">WEIRD</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. but i realy prefer a css only solution and that aolution would make me use jquery or so to add the class when that li is alone.

Comment: @Nori Depending on how you're generating the list, you can add the class in the backend. My guess is your HTML is not static bc you're wanting to cover multiple cases, and you're obviously not using JS, so you must be generating it on the backend. You can check if your list has only one element and then add the class to the `<li>`.

Comment: You could use ```.last:first-child:last-child``` and apply styles on it for the "alone" case. No need for extra classes or JS.

Comment: Genius! do you want to post it as answer or should i?

Comment: @JaKhris That's a great idea! I never thought of that :)

Comment: CSS is beautiful, isn't it?
@Nori Knock yourself out. ;)